# Get the transaction title from an SqlTransaction object

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

When creating an `SqlTransaction` object using `BeginTransaction("MyTransactionName")`, is there a way to get the name of the transaction from the returned transaction object?

The idea is that when my transaction fails, I want to log the name of the transaction as the system is multithreaded and some deadlocks will occur which need to be handled.

The `logger` object in my example code is our own component, and this is a very trivial example as much of the code cannot be posted here.

```
 using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectString)) {
     myConnection.Open();
     SqlTransaction transaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction("UpdateTransaction");

     //The update methods are omitted here for brevity

     try {
         logger.Log("Attempt commit ");
         transaction.Commit();
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         logger.Error("Commit failed - " + ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
         //At this point, I want to write the name of the failed
         //transaction into the log.
     }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you're looking for something much more elegant, but sometimes the simple fix will do the trick. Just save the name in a variable scoped outside the try/catch:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectString)) 
{
     myConnection.Open();
     string txName = "UpdateTransaction";    
     SqlTransaction transaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction(txName);

     //The update methods are omitted here for brevity

     try 
     {
         logger.Log("Attempt commit ");
         transaction.Commit();
     }
     catch (Exception ex) 
     {
         logger.Error($"Commit transaction {txName} failed - " + ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
     }    
}
```

Not ideal, since it creates a string variable that will have to later be garbage collected, but it gets the job done.

**Update:**

Looking at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs,7d950798d897ba05), it doesn't appear that the name is stored anywhere, so there is no way to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another catch block

```
catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
        {
            errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
        }
       logger.Error(errorMessages.ToString());
    }
```